# Using <template is="dom-if" with a condition

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dom-if

I have a `<template is="dom-if" if=...` that I want to use with a logical condition.

Any binding I try appears to be *truthy*:

```html
<link href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="test-thing">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{title == 'foo'}}" restamp>
      Title is <b>FOO</b>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{title}} == 'bar'" restamp>
      Title is <b>BAR</b>
    </template>
    
    Actual: "{{title}}"
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'test-thing',
      properties: {
        title: {type: String,value:''}
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<div>
  Title: foo<br>
  <test-thing title="foo"></test-thing>
</div>
<div>
  Title: bar<br>
  <test-thing title="bar"></test-thing>
</div>
<div>
  Title: abc<br>
  <test-thing title="abc"></test-thing>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to apply an `if` condition to a `dom-if` `template`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you have to define your function.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_isEqualTo(title, 'Foo')]]">
```

and then in script:

```
function _isEqualTo(title, string) {
  return title == string;
}
```

whenever is property `title` changed, function `_isEqualTo` is called. so you don't have to take care of observing property or something.

function `_isEqualTo` is called with 2 parameters, the second one is just plain string you want to compare some value with.

Comment: Thanks Kuba - I realise that I can wrap the condition in a function or add a property that is set when the related property are changed, but is that really the only way? It feels very clunky to extract away a function just so that an `if` block can evaluate the `if`.

Comment: there is no other way. You can use `computed`, or `observer` options of property also. But there isn't anything like {{title == 'foo'}}. You have to get used to it. I was using handlebars before Polymer and it was really annoying for me at the beginning, so i know how you feel about it :D .

Comment: typo '_isEuqalTo'

Answer (score 4):

The only logic you can use in a binding is not. 
for instance:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{_isEqualTo(title, 'Foo')}}">
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!_isEqualTo(title, 'Foo')}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data was such that Foo was boolean or had an attribute that "Foo":true or "isFoo":true . Then you could just do:

```html
<template is="dom-if" if="{{isFoo}}">
   Foo
</template>
```

Comment: The problem is that when the underlying property is changed, the template won't get updated to reflect that change, so the isFoo is not re-evaluated. You have to specify the underlying property as well, as in the other answers is shown. So your solution is not working well.